# Prevent system font from overriding app font in React-Native android

Tags: android, react-native

I need to force app font inside the app and not to be overridden by system font. Namely font size and fontFamily. I also added the font I am using in assets and resources for android and iOS respectively.

rn: 0.42

Answer (score 0):

Just add styles to `Text` component like:
`<Text style={{ fontSize: 13, ... }>some text</Text>`.

If you want to use the same styles everywhere in the app just create your own component:

```
import { Text } from 'react-native';

const MyCustomText = (props) => {
  const { style, children, ...rest } = props;
  return (
    <Text style={[{fontSize: 13}, style]} {...rest}>{children}</Text>
  )
}

export default MyCustomText;
```

Comment: I did this but its still being overridden by the system font on Samsung s4